# Pymongo how to do set on update by not on insert

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, updates

I am trying to update the document if the document is found otherwise insert as follows

```
upserts = [UpdateOne({"$and":[{'_id': x['_id']},{'time':{"$lt": x['time']}}]},
                     {'$setOnInsert': x, '$set':{'time':x['time']}},
                     upsert=True) for x in batch]
collection.bulk_write(upserts)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Updating the path 'time' would create a conflict at 'time'
```

I understand that it's happening because `time` key is getting updated in both `set` and `setOnInsert`.  I cannot specify fields in `setOnInsert` as the keys are not fixed. In case excluding a field in setOnInsert is allowed, then I can exclude `time` in that.

How can I work this around?

Comment: What is the actual query that is sent to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the document is inserted, both the `$set` and `$setOnInsert` documents will be processed.

The query executor is refusing to update the same field twice in a single update.

You might try using a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to remove the time field from the $setOnInsert, like:

```
'$setOnInsert': {i:x[i] for i in x if i!='time'}
```